# SASS - CSS - Animation works in chrome, not in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, firefox, sass

I try to achieve a simple 2 state colour transition for a div

it is in an angular project, it uses scss files for CSS

I found some other threads about this, but even if I try to apply fixes, it still does not work in firefox

here is how I use the code below:

```
@include errorDivPulse($black,$orange,$white,#ff1200,animC);
.errorDiv {
    @include errorDiv($black,$orange,animC);
}
```

it looks like this (just a repetition with prefixes):

```
@mixin errorDiv($foreGround,$backGround,$animName) {
    color: $foreGround !important; 
    background-color: $backGround !important; 

    @if($animName) {
        -moz-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        -ms-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        animation: $animName 1s infinite;
    }
}

@mixin errorDivPulse ($color1, $backGround1, $color2, $backGround2,$animName ) {
    @-moz-keyframes #{$animName} {
        0% {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
        50% {
            color: $color2;
            background-color: $backGround2; 
        }
        100 {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$animName} {
        0% {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
        50% {
            color: $color2;
            background-color: $backGround2; 
        }
        100 {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes #{$animName} {
        0% {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
        50% {
            color: $color2;
            background-color: $backGround2; 
        }
        100 {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
    }
    @keyframes #{$animName} {
        0% {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
        50% {
            color: $color2;
            background-color: $backGround2; 
        }
        100 {
            color: $color1;
            background-color: $backGround1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to start with, you can remove all the prefixed version, they are no more needed

Comment: If you want to use the prefixes you could just use a package like postcss https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer that will prefix properties automatically

Comment: ok, I'd delete the prefixed version, nice to know, but any idea why it's not working ? ...I'll edit the question...

Comment: apparently it has something to do with the !important flag, but if I remove it it displays the default div color, while it should display the colors defined in the animation

Answer (score 0):

the answer was the !importants in the default div css
stupid of me

```
@mixin errorDiv($foreGround,$backGround,$animName) {
    color: $foreGround ; 
    background-color: $backGround ; 

    @if($animName) {
        -moz-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        -ms-animation: $animName 1s infinite;
        animation: $animName 1s infinite;
    }
}
```